# How to draw differently spaced grid lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

On mathworks, I have found a code which is suppossed to draw grid lines in a plot:

```
g_x = -25:1.25:0;
g_y = -35:2.5:-5;
for i = 1:length(g_x)
    plot([g_x(i) g_x(i)],[g_y(1) g_y(end)],'k:')% y grid lines
    hold on
end
for i=1:length(g_y)
    plot([g_x(1) g_x(end)],[g_y(i) g_y(i)],'k:') % x grid lines
    hold on    
end
```

[here's a link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95511-in-matlab-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-grid-at-a-spacing-different-from-the-ticks-on-the-axes)

I don't understand the plot command: e.g. the y grid lines - one of the inputs is a vector containing all the spacing points of the x-axis, where I want to have a grid. These points are given in two columns and they are assigned to the second vector, which only contains the first and the last point shown on the y-axis. As I understand this command, it will for example take the first element g_x(1) and g_y(1) and plot a : , it will then take g_x(2) and g_y(1) and plot :, and so on. But How does it keep on plotting : from g_y(1) continuously until g-y(end) ?

Comment: Why not just use `grid` which is built-in?

Comment: because grid can only plot a gid where the xtick and ytick is, right? I want to have a grid in between as well

Comment: You can use the minor grid lines. What version of MATLAB?

Comment: 2016, never heard of minor grid lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, it simply plots the two *endpoints* of each grid line and since the default `LineStyle` used by `plot` is a solid line, they will automatically be connected. What that code is doing is creating all permutations of endpoints and plotting those to form the grid.

Rather than creating custom plot objects (if you're using R2015b or later), you can simply use the minor grid lines and modify the [locations of the minor tick marks of the `axes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numericruler-properties.html).

```
g_x = -25:1.25:0;
g_y = -35:2.5:-5;

ax = axes('xlim', [-25 0], 'ylim', [-35 -5]);

% Turn on the minor grid lines
grid(ax, 'minor')

% Modify the location of the x and y minor tick marks
ax.XAxis.MinorTickValues = g_x;
ax.YAxis.MinorTickValues = g_y;
```

[image]

Comment: cool, thx! .. for some reason, when I apply your code, I get a warning in the line where I plot the legend: Warning: Error updating Axes.

 Value must be a vector of type single or double whose values increase

Comment: Can you link to your actual code? Chances are you've copied something incorrectly. Make sure that your `xlims` (if you set them) are increasing. I have only set them here for demonstration purposes.

Comment: 'figure
plot(A,B,'sb')
hold on
plot(A,C,'-b')
hold on
plot(D,E,'s')
hold on
plot(D,F,'s')
%grid lines
hold on
g_x = -25:1.25:0;
g_y = -35:2.5:-5;
grid minor


ax = axes('xlim', [-25 0], 'ylim', [-35 -5]);
% Modify the location of the x and y minor tick marks
ax.XAxis.MinorTickValues = g_x;
ax.YAxis.MinorTickValues = g_y;

xlabel('Pin[dBm]')
ylabel('D3')
legend('Measurement1','Measurement2','Measurement3','Measurement4')'

Comment: sorry, how can I mark this as code? I have set ' ... '

Comment: You want to place `ax = axes()` *before* any of your plotting not after it.

Comment: ok, and the grid(ax,'minor') command as well. Now it's working, thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the code does this:

```
g_x = -25:1.25:0;
```

generates a array with values `-25.0000  -23.7500  -22.5000  -21.2500 ... 0`
These are the positions where vertical lines are drawn

The same holds for g_y, but of course this determines where horizontal lines are drawn.
The option `'k'` determined that it is a dashed line.

And the loops just loo through the arrays.
So in the first iteration the plot function draws a line from the position

```
[-25, -35]
```

to the position

```
[-25, -5]
```

So if you want to change the grid, just change the values stored in `g_x`

```
g_x = -25:3.0:0;
```

would for example draw vertical lines with the width `3.0`
I hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: thx for your answer as well. I tried to give you a "thumbs up", but apparently my reputation isn't high enough